# I need to replace the array with the user input, but move the previous array to the right

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class LinkedList {
public Node head, tail;
//constructor method to create a list of object with head, 
tail, 
and size.
public LinkedList() {
head = null;
tail = null;
}
//method add node to end of list
public void addLastNode(int data) {
if (tail == null)
head = tail = new Node(data); //empty list
else {
tail.next = new Node(data); //link new node as last node
tail = tail.next; //make tail pointer points to last node
}
}
//method #1: add first node
public void addFirstNode(int data) {
Node temp = new Node(data);
if (tail==null)
tail = temp;
temp.next = head;
head = temp;
}
//method #2: add node at index
public void addAtIndex(int index, int data) {
if(index<countNodes()) {
if(index==0) {
Node temp = head;
head = new Node(data);
head.next = temp.next;
return;
}
//method #3: remove first node
public void removeFirstNode() {
Node a = head;
Node b = head.next - 1;
}
```

I have this code, and this only replaces the array for example..
[a.b,....d] the user enters replace a with d then the output should be like [d,a,b,.s.d] but my output just replaces it..
how do i change that
for method 3

Comment: Could provide more detail, preferably with a [mre]? Currently, you talk about an array but the little bit of code you've provided looks more like a linked list.

Comment: I made changes to the code

Comment: ... you haven't shown how you're trying to REPLACE one value with another...

Comment: Do you simply mean `head=head.next;`?

Comment: To be honest, your question is still not clear to me. Where is this "array" you mention? If your goal is to _insert_ a user-defined element at the head of the list, why is "method 3" named `removeFirstNode`? And, if that _is_ your goal, how is that not already implemented by `addFirstNode`?